# IE11 throws "Can't reach this page" INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE for HTTP, but all fine for HTTPS

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-10-v1709

I'm having a strange issue throughout my domain, affecting all computers in my domain. Loading a site in `http://`, using specifically IE (No issues in Chrome), results in 
 `Can't reach this page INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE`, whereas adding `https://` resolves this problem. Its like redirection to HTTPS is not working, but strangely enough, adding the site to compatibility view resolves the issue.

For example, navigating to `http://google.ca` results in `INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE`, whereas navigating to `https://google.ca` loads normally. Adding `google.ca` to compatibility view resolves the problem, with HTTP and HTTPS working as intended.

- As far as connections go, Wireshark shows a sequence of packets ending with `Reset: Set` when loading `http://google.ca`: [Wireshark packets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lp5PD.png)
- I should also note the IE Developer Console shows nothing of interest: [IE Dev Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ot4n8.png)

This happens on all versions and builds of IE and we have some that are on the latest versions and some that are not. Disabling Endpoint Protection and local firewalls have no effect.

Any ideas on what might be some good steps to take to narrow down the cause of this here?
Thanks everyone!!!

Comment: Have you tried disabling all add-ons? Also, have you checked the proxy settings?

Comment: I have, and in fact the test computer I'm using to troubleshoot the issue is a clean computer with no addons installed. No proxy is in place. I appreciate the suggestion James! =)

Answer (score 0):

Found this question when my workplace installed a system update for IE11 ... the underlying problem is that there are cached credentials for the website and the update changed the way IE stores it's credentials so it can no longer access the ones previously stored.  You can get around the problem by deleting your cached credentials for the site.

Comment: Did that indeed give you problems for HTTP but not for HTTPS?